# how to use connect windows vias LDAP

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I am new to windows AD .

I would like to use Softerra LDAP browser to connect windows server ( localhost ) , I just would like to use "administrator" user to connect windows server , would advise what I need to input in Principal field eg. cn= , ou= , o= ?

I tried to input cn=administrator then input password but it pops " The supplied credential is invalid" .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use simple bind authentification you need to give all the DN of the administrator user like this :

```
CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=SILOGIX-ESS01,DC=local
```

You can find the Distinguished Name using the computers and users MMC :

Right click on the user (administrator) in users container -> Properties -> Attributes Editor -> distinguishedName.